# Image loaded normally via <img> HTML element but CORS failing when loaded programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

first a little bit of context.

I'm working on a React web app and my object, `Product`, it has an array of images. The image object is pretty simple: `{ url: string, id: string }`. The images are loading fine as you can see bellow:

[image]

When you click on the scissors icon it pops up a crop container. The crop container uses [react-cropper](https://github.com/react-cropper/react-cropper), internally what that package does is the following:

```js
//...
if (this.options.checkCrossOrigin && isCrossOriginURL(url)) {
  if (!crossOrigin) {
    crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  } // Bust cache when there is not a "crossOrigin" property (#519)


  crossOriginUrl = addTimestamp(url);
}

this.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;
this.crossOriginUrl = crossOriginUrl;
var image = document.createElement('img');

if (crossOrigin) {
  image.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;
}

image.src = crossOriginUrl || url;
image.alt = element.alt || 'The image to crop';
this.image = image;
//...
```

Sometimes the image loads normally but most of the time I get the error:

```
Access to image at 'https://url.to.image?timestamp=1639579791237' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

That `timestamp` param is added by `react-cropper` to avoid CORS error. I did a deploy to my DEV environment to see if it would work in a live scenario but still got the same error.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: _"That `timestamp` param is added by `react-cropper` to avoid CORS error."_ Can you elaborate why the timestamp should do anything about CORS?

Comment: @jabaa honestly I don't know, that's how it works on their internal code. They check if the image URL is a CORS and, if so, they add the `timestamp` param.

Comment: `?timestamp=1639579791237` is a query parameter, and query parameters aren't a part of an origin. The timestamp doesn't change anything about CORS. It changes caching behavior and this technique is usually called Cache Buster. "Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port" [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) You have two options. 1) Same origin using a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or 2) [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers.

Comment: @jabaa I've already tried with headers but it didn't work but haven't thought on using a reverse proxy. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Do you have access to the backend? The CORS have to be sent by the backend.

Comment: @jabaa that is the thing. The image is hosted in a bucket on AWS and the URL if actually the URL of the image and not an backend endpoint for it. In any case that was what the backend dev of the team told me.

Comment: AFAIK you can configure AWS to send CORS headers but I don't know how. The reverse proxy always works.